# Android application design: Right split between activities, services and threads?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I'm currently trying to finish the design of a larger app which is used for remote controlling wireless devices via a proprietary wireless bridge, a USB host device using CDC.

But right now I'm stuck in how to make the correct split between Activities, Services / IntentServices and worker threads.....

The application will be made of these fundamentals:
 - Various GUI screens which offcourse will all be Activities. I intend to have some threads for receiving a few messages and updating the GUI accordingly via handlers upon these message receptions. - any comments on that approach?

- A module handling all low level USB/CDC communiation, message serialization/deserialization and message dispathing to the application via queues. This calls for a seperate thread. I don't want this thread to be destroyed just because the activity that spawned it goes away - which in my book calls for an IntentService - right?
- Some sequence players which will control the wireless devices in a timed manner. These will be triggered from one my activities and MUST run to the end without stopping due to home button presses, launch of other activities etc. - Again this calls for a IntentService.....right?
- A status module updating some "global" data structures (possibly a database) upon message reception from the low level module. Here I am puzzled...coulmd this just be a working thread in my main Activity - or am I looking at a third IntentService?

Would it be better to include all in one service and then just add threads where needed?

Sorry for my noobiness  - Android is hard for C++ programmers who have been programming non GUI backgroud tasks for the last century.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bullets one and two you are right that a service is the best approach. An IntentService in particular is good to handle jobs one by one that were sent from somewhere else.

If your service should only keep a particular thread alive which does the message/queue handling on its own (as I understand bullet one), a normal service may be enough.

For bullet three it depends if those updates must be done while your app is not visibly active to the user. If so, use a service as well.

By the way: A thread is not bound to a particular activity or service but to a process. If this process contains a running service then all threads in it are kept alive as well (except the process must be killed due to special circumstances).

Comment: So a thread spawned where ever in an app (process) is only killed at the time of the process is killed? Just to make it clear for me then....is it ONLY member varibles of the Activity class that dies when onDestroy() is called? In that case singletons persists untill the prcess is killed?

If that is the case....why do I need the service/intentservice? A standalone thread or two and a singleton interface holding some messagequeues would be just fine (seen by my c++ eyes - I know there is a good reason....so please enlighten me :))

Comment: @user2500605 Singletons/static members of a class persist as long as the process is alive. A service is needed for two things: Handling requests from the outside world in a standardized manner (if necessary) and to tell the system that this process is more important (and shouldn't be killed early), see the ranks of importance described at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle

Comment: @Michaael Butscher Thanks allot - glad you had the time to comment. It helped me to conclude the design and start coding!